# I couldn't figure out why is the conncection is closed

Tags: reactjs, axios, wordpress-rest-api

I'm posting data to the wordpress api but I got this problem of closed connection .. first time it was working but I dont know what happened

```
handleSignIn = () => {
        const post = {
            "email" : this.state.email,
            "password " : this.password
        }
        axios.post('http://api.piri.ai:3000/v1/public/login' , post)
            .then(res => {this.setState({status: res.data.status})  
            //window.location= '/wp';
            console.log(res.data)
        })
            .catch(e => {console.log(e.message) ; this.setState({status: false})});


    }
```

in the console log, I got this error

Network Error
xhr.js:166 OPTIONS https://api.piri.ai:3000/v1/public/login net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Updated Answer

I have tested your API with postman and it's working fine in postman. See below image.
[image]

Also integrate it in react application as well. But the actual issue is **CORS**. So for that your server should enable the cross origin requests.

[image]

### Old Answer

Can you add below code in header

```
 headers:{
     'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
     'Accept': 'application/json'
}
```

You can handle network error in catch part like below.

```
catch(error => {
  if (!error.response) {
      // network error
      this.errorStatus = 'Error: Network Error';
  } else {
      this.errorStatus = error.response.data.message;
  }
})
```

Comment: It gives me just the previous error, it doesn't tell me what kind of error it is

Comment: Please update your header as i updated my answer. Hope this will work for you!

Comment: on package.json ?

Comment: No. add in headers of axios.

Comment: the same output on the log :(

Comment: Make Sure "http://" is in your URL Address. Might be this one is also one of the reason.

Comment: no result again, its such a pain, Ive been trying these two days for a solution

Comment: As you mention the error in question, It seem your API pointing to the `https://api.piri.ai:3000/v1/public/login` instead of `http://api.piri.ai:3000/v1/public/login`.

Comment: The issue with CORS. So can you please enable it from backend. I have updated my answer with screenshot.

Comment: Thanks I will ask the client to enable it in WP

Comment: Great. Can you please mark an answer as accepted and Vote up? So it will be helpful for other developers as well.